# Php date default timezone doesnt return the correct value of unix timestamp conversion

Tags: php

Am trying to convert time in unix format to php date time So i have tried the following

```
    $timezone = "America/Guayaquil";
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    var_dump(date("Y-m-d h:m:s", time()))
```

When i check the above it doesn't return the actual local time

Note that the value of time is a specific timestamp example

```
1528825868
```

How do i go on about this as it gives incorrect time

Comment: What result are you getting, and what result are you expecting?  Seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: Why do you think it is not working? https://3v4l.org/p5s90

Comment: Well your time format seems off. In the minute position you use `m` which is the month, so you might use `i`. Also be aware that `h` is only the 12-hour format, if you expect  24 hour format use `H`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP version? (php -v)

Have you tried with:

```
ini_set( 'date.timezone', 'America/Guayaquil' );
```

You can check if the timezone is being correctly set by doing

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Guayaquil');
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
} else {
  echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php